# Automatically add properties based on tag in Org outlines

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I'd like to be able to configure org to add properties based on specific tags which are used to describe the outline item.

For instance, say we have a list item `* user  :person:student:`. I'd like to have the `person` tag add the properties `age` and `name`, and the `student` tag to add the properties `major`.

How would I go about implementing this functionality?